# How to verify/test Apache server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to Apache server and Ubuntu.

I have Apache/2.4.29 installed on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

I was working on compliance/security issue on this Linux box.

My manager asked me to **verify/test Apache server**.

How do I go about doing this?

What are some of basic steps I could take?

I tried searching at Google, but this area is so broad, so I cannot focus where to go.

Comment: Why don’t you ask your manager what they mean instead of asking random strangers to guess for you?

Comment: Your question lacks objective and is too open ended. Perhaps what you really mean is you'd like to test whether your webserver is running and how you can display a test page. Again, we have no idea what you are trying to drive at with this question, so you'd need to be a bit more clear

Answer (score 0):

If your manager is asking for a basic connectivity test the simplest answer is to create an index.html file, copy  it to the root folder of your server and then connect using a browser pointing to your server IP address.

Something like http://192.168.0.6

Here are a couple links to get you started:

http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643880/how-can-i-create-a-phpinfo.php-page

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Vilmos. What about security-related test?

Comment: The approach to testing your server installation is a much more complex issue and is dependent on what else you have installed. You should probably ask the question separately. There are many online scanners, https://geekflare.com/online-scan-website-security-vulnerabilities/ and there are plenty of guides on hardening your installation https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/10-tips-secure-apache-installation/. The first step is to make sure you have proper firewalling in place and have turned off any services that are not needed. Plus keep EVERYTHING up to date.